# Select Max inside a mysql Insert Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`Max(sequence) + 1` (based on my knowledge) should be returning the highest sequence with `$_GET['business_id']` in the database + 1 - existing values in the database are 0, 1, and 3 - so `max(sequence)+1` should be 4 - so something must be wrong with the line of code.  Any ideas?

```
$insertQuery = "
    INSERT INTO owner_business_media 
        (business_id, sequence, type, filename, title, secret)
    VALUES (
        '".$_GET[businessid]."', 
        '(SELECT MAX(sequence)+1 FROM owner_business_media WHERE business_id=".$_GET['businessid'].")', 
        '$type', 
        '$fullfile', 
        '$filename', 
        '1')
";
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove single quotes that surround the inner `SELECT` and instead of the regular `INSERT` go with [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html):

```
$insertQuery = "
    INSERT INTO owner_business_media
        (business_id, sequence, type, filename, title, secret)
    SELECT
        '".intval($_GET['businessid'])."',
        (SELECT MAX(obm.sequence)+1 FROM owner_business_media obm WHERE obm.business_id=".intval($_GET['businessid']).") AS next,
        '$type', 
        '$fullfile', 
        '$filename', 
        '1'
";
```

Also, never embed a `GET` variable directly without validating or sanitizing it's contents (see `intval($_GET['businessid'])`). Otherwise the code gets exposed to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks - for some reason, the query doesn't save if there's no quotes around the SELECT, but when there are single quotes around the select, it gives me a 0 instead of a 4 - any idea why this may be?

Comment: Did you run your subquery in a GUI or MySQL prompt to check if it even works? Also, if you need a sequence_id incremented by 1 at every insert, try to look into MySQL triggers.

Comment: @Bob Cavezza: A single-quoted literal inside a query is treated like a regular string so having 0 is quite logical. I updated the code sample, previous version had a couple of bugs in it.

Comment: I was receiving an error (#1093) that I can't use a call from a table inside of a table that's being updated.  So I was forced to use the MAX call outside of this table.

Comment: @Bob Cavezza: The above query is different from the initial one and works just fine, at least on MySQL 5.1.36. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as the other answer, yet not completely the same:

```
$insertQuery = "
    INSERT INTO owner_business_media
        (business_id, sequence, type, filename, title, secret)
    SELECT
        '".intval($_GET['businessid'])."',
        MAX(sequence)+1 AS next,
        '$type', 
        '$fullfile', 
        '$filename', 
        '1'
    FROM owner_business_media
    WHERE business_id=".intval($_GET['businessid']);
```

Maybe it would be safer to use IFNULL with `sequence` (in case the table is empty), like this:

```
        MAX(IFNULL(sequence, 0))+1 AS next
```